# lint and mypy error when importing queue

Tags: python, mypy

I am trying to import the `queue` something like this

```
import sys
is_py2 = sys.version[0] == '2'
if is_py2:
    import Queue as queue
else:
    import queue as queue
```

However lint is complaining saying

```
Unnecessary import alias - rewrite as 'import queue'
```

and mypy is complaining saying

```
Name 'queue' already defined
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try `import queue` instead of `import queue as queue`

Answer (score 1):

You should either edit your code to look like this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    import Queue as queue
else:
    import queue as queue
```

...or alternatively, keep your code as-is and run either:

```
# Type-check your code assuming it will be run using python 3
mypy your_code.py --always-false py_2

# Type-check your code assuming it will be run using python 2
mypy your_code.py --always-true py_3 --py2
```

The upshot is that mypy understands very basic ["platform checks"](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#version-and-platform-checks), including if statements that use `sys.version_info`. (Mypy does not understand code using `sys.version`, though).

Mypy also will not check any branches that it knows is unreachable. These two features in combination will make mypy only ever load one of the two modules.

That said, if you decide to use `sys.version_info` checks, you have to repeat that check everywhere instead of using the constant: it's simply too intractable for mypy to keep track of extra metadata associated with a constant except in certain limited cases, so it doesn't bother.

Thankfully, mypy does come with a mechanism that lets you tell mypy to assume a particular constant will always be true or false -- the `--always-false CONST` and `--always-true CONST` flags.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the 'better ask for forgiveness' design rule in Python and do it like this:

```
try:
    import queue
except ImportError:
    import Queue as queue
```

Comment: Try this (before attempting to import): `print ( type(queue), repr(queue)) ` to see what it is and (hopefully) find out where it is defined.